# How to force browser to open save as dialog, even if download folder was set?

Tags: javascript, php, browser, http-headers, frontend

If the user has chosen to store all downloads in a spesific folder, is there a way to force browser to open "save as" dialog upon download and make user select the folder?

Answer (score 0):

You cant do that, also downloader can be not a browser, but other software that does not have any possibilities to open such dialogs.